# Is it possible to divorce, with children (under 18), in TN without a lawyer or mediator?

Tags: divorce, tennessee

Is it possible to divorce, with children (under 18) in Davison county TN without a lawyer or mediator if both parents have filled a parenting plan and in total agreement?

We've been researching but cannot find any forms that allow a married couple (4 years) with children (under 18) to fill out and bring to court where they can be signed off and our divorce made official. Everything I've read so far is about divorcing for those without children, and that it's suggested to go with a mediator or lawyer otherwise. But there must be a way to do this without hiring these $300/hr services, especially when the parents are not contesting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[COURT-APPROVED DIVORCE FORMS](https://www.tncourts.gov/help-center/court-approved-divorce-forms)

These divorce forms were approved by the Tennessee Supreme Court as "universally acceptable as legally sufficient". This means that if the forms are filled out correctly that all Tennessee courts that hear divorce cases must accept the forms.

Instructions to Divorce Forms  (Please read this first)

```
Form 1 – Request for Divorce    Word    PDF Fillable PDF
Form 2 – Spouses' Personal Information  Word    PDF FIllable PDF
Form 3 – Request to Postpone Filing Fees    Word    PDF Fillable PDF
Form 4 – Health Insurance Notice    Word    PDF Fillable PDF
Form 5 – Divorce Agreement  Word    PDF Fillable PDF
Form 6 – Final Decree of Divorce    Word    PDF FIllable PDF
Form 7 – Restraining Order for Divorcing Spouses    Word    PDF Fillable PDF
Form 8 – Notice of Hearing  Word    PDF Fillable PDF
```

This is a no-fault divorce form for use within the State of Tennessee (PETITION FOR DIVORCE). Most courts will require that this form be completed and filed along with a [Marital Settlement Agreement (Minor Children)](https://www.ilrg.com/forms/divorce-mc-setag/us/tn).

Comment: Right, but the first thing it says on the "Please read this first" above the forms is: "If you have NO children who are under 18, disabled or in high school and you do not own buildings or land or a business with your spouse, or have retirement benefits."

Comment: This is a no-fault divorce form for use within the State of Tennessee (PETITION FOR DIVORCE). Most courts will require that this form be completed and filed along with a [Marital Settlement Agreement (Minor Children)](https://www.ilrg.com/forms/divorce-mc-setag/us/tn).

Comment: @RockyAssad Did the Marital Settlement Agreement Minor Children Form help?